# Parse value from output using AWK

Tags: sed, awk

I need to parse the value, after the 100th of a second from output, from an FTP get command.

`ftp> 8.591220.98disconnect`

With assistance from Stack members I've been using the following to obtain the data:

```
ut1intput=$(awk 'NR==70{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i=="ftp>")print $(i+1)} filename.txt)
```

I'm using `sed` to strip the word "disconnect" from the output, but am perplexed as to how to print only the 100th of a second output, i.e.: `8.591220.98`

Is `awk` the right tools for this task?

I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: What do you mean by `100th of a second output`? Do you really want the whole `8.591220.98` token, or just the portion after the last `.`? Given that `8.591220.98` is not a valid number, what exactly does it represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve just the immediate problem:

If all you need is to extract the number-like token from your input data, you could simply use `tr` as follows:

```
tr -C -d '0-9.' <<<'ftp> 8.591220.98disconnect' # -> '8.591220.98'
```

---

But it makes more sense to integrate the desired operation into your original `awk` program, using `sub()`, as in @Håkon Hægland's answer:

```
ut1intput=$(awk '
  NR==70 {
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { 
      if($i=="ftp>") {
        sub(/disconnect$/, "", $(i+1));  # remove 'disconnect' suffix
        print $(i+1)
      }
    }
  }' filename.txt)
```

Comment: You don't want to use brackets for sets in `tr`, [they are not required](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/utilities/tr.html) and may lead to unexpected results depending on the string in question and its parsing. Consider: `tr '.-' '12' <<< '._[]?='` => `1_[]?=` vs. `tr '[.-]' '[12]' <<< '._[]?='` => `1_]]]]`. You only want to use them for character classes.

Answer (score 0):

The awk command  `sub(/disconnect/,"", $i)` will strip the word `disconnect` from field number `$i`. For instance:

```
echo "8.591220.98disconnect" | awk '{sub(/disconnect/,"", $1)}1'
```

gives:

```
8.591220.98
```